# how to simplify the same code in two else condition PHP

Tags: php

There are two 'else' condition with the same code, so how to simplify this code?

```
if(!empty($data))
{
  $getData = $this->getData($data);
  if(!empty($getData))
  {
    $response = $getData->name;
  }
  else
  {
    $response = $this->getRequest($value);
  }
}
else
{
  $response = $this->getRequest($value);
}

return $response;
```

Comment: I think this is a simple code

Comment: @mshomali but there is still a duplicate code right? how to reuse this code $response = $this->getRequest($value);

Answer (score 2):

Get the response from `getData()`, and in a second step, check if `$response` is set, and if not, get the value from `getRequest()`:

```
if (!empty($data)) {
  $getData = $this->getData($data);
  if (!empty($getData)) {
    $response = $getData->name;
  }
}

$response = $response ?? $this->getRequest($value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
if(!empty($data)) {
    $getData = $this->getData($data);
    if(!empty($getData)) {
        $response = $getData->name;
    }
}

if ($response == null) { // Or check if the $response is not filled yet
    $response = $this->getRequest($value);
}

return $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
$response = $this->getRequest($value);

if(!empty($data)){
    $getData = $this->getData($data);
    if(!empty($getData))
    {
        $response = $getData->name;
    }
}

return $response;
```

Comment: Well, if `getRequest` is slow, it might not be a good idea to execute it unconditionally. `getData` may also have side effects that affect the value of `getRequest`, though I would hope that isn't the case for something that starts with "get".

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($data) && ($getData = $this->getData($data)) && !empty($getData))
{
  $response = $getData->name;
}
else
{
  $response = $this->getRequest($value);
}

return $response;
```

Comment: I really don't think it's ever a good idea to assign in a a conditional check, especially on `if``.